# hideSoftInputFromWindow throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, kotlin, inputmethodmanager

I have code in Java that hides the soft keyboard using the InputMethodManager. When I convert the code to Kotlin, the same code throws a NoMethodFound exception.

I can easily switch between the Java and Kotlin versions and demonstrate the correct behaviour in Java and incorrect behaviour in Kotlin.

Java code

```java
            searchText.clearFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)dialog.getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            try {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                String stop = "here";
            }
```

Kotlin code

```
            searchText!!.clearFocus()
            val imm = dialog!!.context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            try {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchText!!.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                val stop = "here"
            }
```

The Java code exhibits the correct behaviour and dismisses the soft keyboard.
The Kotlin code throws the exception

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   hideSoftInputFromWindow(Landroid/os/IBinder;I)V in class
>   Landroid/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager' appears
>   in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)"

Answer (score 0):

It look like this method not available in `Context`. Try use `Context` from your application Context. For getting Context of application do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/paraya3636/bf8108a75eb49323e56c0c90dd0747e0) or some googling about getting application in kotlin may help.

Comment: The code in the original question runs in a dialog within an activity started as an intent from a main activity. Using your suggestion, I have determined that the application context is identical to the activity context but different from the dialog context. However, both contexts provide the same InputMethodManager.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a workaround.
I refactored the Kotlin code back into Java and placed it as a static method in a helper class. The method is called from Kotlin.

```
public class DialogHelper {
public static void hideKeyboard(EditText searchText, Dialog dialog) {
    searchText.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)dialog.getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    try {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        String stop = "here";
    }
}
```

}

Now the code works like it's supposed to: the soft keyboard is hidden and no exception is thrown.

I still wonder if anyone can shed any light on why this works and the straight Kotlin code does not.